# Securing property in a class library and requiring a only a certain method to set it

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I have a class library (call it Lib1) that can be used in other project (call it Lib2).

Lib1 has a lot of static methods, but in order to be able to call them from Lib2 another method in Lib1: `Configure()` is required to run on the application start just once. This method should set a property (again, just once), and every time a static method from Lib1 is called, the property should be evaluated (lets say it needs to be equal to 5).

It is my understanding that the property needs to be static. However, the issue then is that this property can be hacked to be any value.

Instead the code that I require to run in Lib1:

```
Lib1.Configure() // sets property to 5
```

Someone could just write this:

```
(typeof(Lib1)).GetProperty("propertyName").SetValue((object)null, 5)
```

How can I assure that this hack would not fly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the answer you are looking for, but it's the only correct answer: **You cannot.** Anything in the memory of a PC you do not control can be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static constructor and initialize your static read only field to the value (5 in your case) that you require.

```
public class YourClass{
  private static readonly int yourCheckField;

  static YourClass() { yourCheckField = 5 }
```

}

Comment: Even if the field is readonly, its value can be modified with reflection.

Comment: @meziantou, How do you modify the value of a read-only member from outside. Note that this is not a property with a backing field.

Comment: `typeof(YourClass).GetField("yourCheckField", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(null, 42);`

Comment: @meziantou, I am behind an approach without reflecting type members.